# Best way to test HTTP queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, odata

I'm currently working on a gem for a Rails app to do very basic operations on an Odata service (retrieve info regarding ski resorts).
I would like to test it properly using Rspec, but cannot manage to write relevant and efficient tests for it.
You can find the gem's code on github, it's pretty basic (core code in lib/anmsm_ruby.rb and tests in the spec folder)
https://github.com/alpinelab/anmsm_ruby

What do you Rspec experts think is the best approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I test an external web `API` use the advantage of the [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gem.

VCR recordes a real HTTP response from the web service and stores it in a `.yml` fixture, called  `cassette`.

That way you can for example test if the returned array of the `all_resorts` method has the expected values/items.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this gem, it helped a lot !